# Pandas make new column from string slice of another column

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a new column in Pandas using a string sliced for another column in the dataframe.

For example.

```
Sample  Value  New_sample
AAB     23     A
BAB     25     B
```

Where `New_sample` is a new column formed from a simple `[:1]` slice of `Sample`

I've tried a number of things to no avail - I feel I'm missing something simple.

What's the most efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 144, accepted):

You can call the `str` method and apply a slice, this will be much quicker than the other method as this is vectorised (thanks @unutbu):

```
df['New_Sample'] = df.Sample.str[:1]
```

You can also call a lambda function on the df but this will be slower on larger dataframes:

```
In [187]:

df['New_Sample'] = df.Sample.apply(lambda x: x[:1])
df
Out[187]:
  Sample  Value New_Sample
0    AAB     23          A
1    BAB     25          B
```

Answer (score 22):

Adding solution to a common variation **when the slice width varies** across DataFrame Rows:

```
#--Here i am extracting the ID part from the Email (i.e. the part before @)

#--First finding the position of @ in Email
d['pos'] = d['Email'].str.find('@')

#--Using position to slice Email using a lambda function
d['new_var'] = d.apply(lambda x: x['Email'][0:x['pos']],axis=1)

#--Imagine x['Email'] as a string on which, slicing is applied
```

Hope this Helps !

Comment: Thanks for adding this common variation solution, just what I was looking for! And to combine into a single line:

`d['new_var'] = d.apply(lambda x: x['Email'][0:x['Email'].find('@')],axis=1)`

Comment: You could also do d["new_var"] = np.vectorize(lambda x : x.split("@")[0])(np.array(d["Email"],dtype=str)), which would spare you an extra column.

Answer (score 18):

You can also use `slice()` to slice string of `Series` as following:

```
df['New_sample'] = df['Sample'].str.slice(0,1)
```

From [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.slice.html#pandas.Series.str.slice):

> Series.str.slice(start=None, stop=None, step=None)
>
> > Slice substrings from each element in the Series/Index

For slicing index (*if index is of type string*), you can try:

```
df.index = df.index.str.slice(0,1)
```

Comment: is there any preference between `df.somecolumn.str[0:1]` and `df.somecolumn.str.slice(0,1)`?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a solution for when you want to take the second element from your pandas dataframe index, which is a tuple, and move it into its own column. Not sure if there is a shorter way to do this but this way works:

```
df["newcol"]=df.index
df["newcol"]=df["newcol"].apply(lambda x: x[1])
```