# Pandas add new columns based on splitting another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split, multiple-columns

I have a pandas dataframe like the following:

```
A              B
US,65,AMAZON   2016
US,65,EBAY     2016
```

My goal is to get to look like this:

```
A              B      country    code    com
US.65.AMAZON   2016   US         65      AMAZON
US.65.AMAZON   2016   US         65      EBAY
```

I know this question has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745022/pandas-dataframe-how-do-i-split-a-column-into-two) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25789445/pandas-make-new-column-from-string-slice-of-another-column#_=_) but **none** of them works for me. I have tried:

```
df['country','code','com'] = df.Field.str.split('.')
```

and

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.Field.str.split('.').tolist(),columns = ['country','code','com','A','B'])
```

Am I missing something? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with parameter `expand=True` and add one `[]` to left side:

```
df[['country','code','com']] = df.A.str.split(',', expand=True)
```

Then [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) `,` to `.`:

```
df.A = df.A.str.replace(',','.')

print (df)
              A     B country code     com
0  US.65.AMAZON  2016      US   65  AMAZON
1    US.65.EBAY  2016      US   65    EBAY
```

Another solution with `DataFrame` constructor if there are no `NaN` values:

```
df[['country','code','com']] = pd.DataFrame([ x.split(',') for x in df['A'].tolist() ])
df.A = df.A.str.replace(',','.')
print (df)
              A     B country code     com
0  US.65.AMAZON  2016      US   65  AMAZON
1    US.65.EBAY  2016      US   65    EBAY
```

Also you can use column names in constructor, but then [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) is necessary:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame([x.split(',') for x in df['A'].tolist()],columns= ['country','code','com'])
df.A = df.A.str.replace(',','.')
df = pd.concat([df, df1], axis=1)
print (df)
              A     B country code     com
0  US.65.AMAZON  2016      US   65  AMAZON
1    US.65.EBAY  2016      US   65    EBAY
```

Comment: Great explanation specifically for the second approach. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

For getting the new columns I would prefer doing it as following:

```
df['Country'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: x[0])
df['Code'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: x[1])
df['Com'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: x[2])
```

As for the replacement of **,** with a **.** you can use the following:

```
df['A'] = df['A'].str.replace(',','.')
```

Answer (score 1):

This will not give the output as expected
it will only give the df['A'] first value which is 'U'

This is okay to create column based on provided data
df1=pd.DataFrame([x.split(',') for x in df['A'].tolist()],columns= ['country','code','com'])

instead of for lambda also can be use