# Duplicate DataFrame Rows based on Column values within each cell

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a Dataframe as shown Below, I have to duplicate rows using the comma as a delimiter. It's easier to understand once you see the dataframes below!:

```
ID      Fruit
10000   Apple, Orange, Pear
10001   Apple, Banana
```

I want to Dataframe below:

```
ID      Fruit
10000   Apple 
10000   Orange
10000   Pear
10001   Apple 
10001   Banana
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas add new columns based on splitting another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38956778/pandas-add-new-columns-based-on-splitting-another-column)

Comment: Here u go: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38956805/11610186

Comment: I'm not sure it's the same, I'm not splitting the column into more columns, but more rows?

Comment: Sorry, you're right - it's a case for ```explode``` - check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `df` looks like this:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [10000, 10001], 'Fruit': ['Apple, Orange, Pear', 'Apple, Banana']})
>>> print(df)
      ID                Fruit
0  10000  Apple, Orange, Pear
1  10001        Apple, Banana
```

you can use the [`pandas.DataFrame.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) method to make a new column of lists consisting of dictionaries with new rows. And after that, you can concatenate these lists in order to make a new data frame out of them. The code is following:

```
>>> df['new'] = df.apply(lambda row: [{'ID': row.ID, 'Fruit': item} for item in row.Fruit.split(', ')], axis=1)
>>> df_new = pd.DataFrame(df.new.sum())
>>> print(df_new)
      ID   Fruit
0  10000   Apple
1  10000  Orange
2  10000    Pear
3  10001   Apple
4  10001  Banana
```

Comment: Thanks, that's really useful.

Comment: That's bad approach- you should rather avoid using ```.apply(...)```, unless you really have to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54432584/11610186

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
df['Fruit']=df['Fruit'].str.split(", ")
df=df.explode('Fruit')
```

Outputs:

```py
      ID   Fruit
0  10000   Apple
0  10000  Orange
0  10000    Pear
1  10001   Apple
1  10001  Banana
```