# How to create column in pandas with part of another column?

Tags: python, pandas

In Python 3 and pandas I have a dataframe with a column of codes. The column "cnpj"

```
segura.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 35581 entries, 0 to 35580
Data columns (total 3 columns):
cnpj            35581 non-null object
nome_empresa    35581 non-null object
estado          35581 non-null object
dtypes: object(3)
memory usage: 834.0+ KB
```

This column always has 14 digits. Example: "00529528000152" and "02197190000104"

Please, can I create a new column that has the first eight digits of column "cnpj" in its rows? Example: "00529528" and "02197190"

Comment: `df.cnpj.str[:8]` ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25789445/pandas-make-new-column-from-string-slice-of-another-column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
segura['NEW_ID'] = segura['cnpj'].str[:8]
```