# Make new column from slice of string from one column pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

I read the answer at the link [Text] ([Pandas make new column from string slice of another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25789445/pandas-make-new-column-from-string-slice-of-another-column)), but it does not solve my problem.

df

```
  SKU        Noodles    FaceCream  BodyWash   Powder      Soap 
 Jan10_Sales    122        100        50        200         300
 Feb10_Sales    100        50         80        90          250
 Mar10_sales    40         30         100       10          11
```

and so on

Now I want column month and year which will take value from SKU Column and return Jan for month and 10 for year (2010).

```
 df['month']=df['SKU'].str[0:3]
 df['year']=df['SKU'].str[4:5]
```

I get KeyError: 'SKU'

```
Doing other things to understand why the error, I perform the following:

 [IN]df.index.name
 [OUT]None

  [IN]df.columns
  [OUT]Index(['Noodles','FaceCream','BodyWash','Powder','Soap'], dtype='object', name='SKU')
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think first column is index, so use `.index`, also for `year` change `4:5` slicing to `3:5`, `0` is possible omit in `0:3`:

```
df['month']=df.index.str[:3]
df['year']=df.index.str[3:5]
print (df)
             Noodles  FaceCream  BodyWash  Powder  Soap month year
SKU                                                               
Jan10_Sales      122        100        50     200   300   Jan   10
Feb10_Sales      100         50        80      90   250   Feb   10
Mar10_sales       40         30       100      10    11   Mar   10
```

Comment: How can i make 10 to 2010?

Comment: Your answer solved my question. upvoted it and will accept as soon as I am allowed

Comment: @ShailajaGuptaKapoor - all datetimes are `>2000` ? Then use `df['year']= 2000 + df.index.str[3:5].astype(int)`