# Split column in python pandas into two columns

Tags: python, pandas, split

I want to split the entry (always a string containing 6 letters) of a column 'Compared Image Type' of a pandas dataframe into two new columns of which one contains the first three letters, the other contains the last three letters of the original column.

```
Name    BaseImage Type  Compared Image Type
 2       oldNeg             semNeg
 2       oldNeu             perNeu
 2       oldNeu             semNeu
 2       oldNeu             newNeu
 2       oldNeg             perNeg
```

So far I've only found out how to split a column after a certain character (e.g. after a ",") and would be thankful for any help.

Comment: `df['Compared Image Type'].str.slice(0, 3)` and `df['Compared Image Type'].str.slice(3)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas make new column from string slice of another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25789445/pandas-make-new-column-from-string-slice-of-another-column)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `str` access:

```
df['col1'] = df['Compared Image Type'].str[:3]
df['col2'] = df['Compared Image Type'].str[3:]
```

OUtput:

```
   Name BaseImage Type Compared Image Type col1 col2
0     2         oldNeg              semNeg  sem  Neg
1     2         oldNeu              perNeu  per  Neu
2     2         oldNeu              semNeu  sem  Neu
3     2         oldNeu              newNeu  new  Neu
4     2         oldNeg              perNeg  per  Neg
```

Based on your data, you can also use a similar approach to split a column using certain character, here capital letters `[A-Z]`:

```
df['Compared Image Type'].str.extract('^(\w*)([A-Z]\w*)')
```

Output:

```
     0    1
0  sem  Neg
1  per  Neu
2  sem  Neu
3  new  Neu
4  per  Neg
```