# how to extract string and create new column in python using list comprehension?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a data frame (df) having "Name" column

```
Name
t_gh_m
t_mr_h
t_gh_u
t_mr_h
t_z_z
```

and I want to create a column name "group" will ll give me ["gh", "mr"] in return if exist or else nun

**my approach**
df["group"] =  [i for i in df["Name"] for j in ["gh","mr"] if j not in i return np.nun else]
But it is an error

**Expected output**

```
 Name       group
t_gh_m       "gh"
t_mr_h       "mr"
t_gh_u       "gh"
t_mr_h       "mr"
t_z_z        nan
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the pandas str (regex) `extract` method:

```
df['group'] = df['Name'].str.extract('_(..)_')
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like in this question would probably work here:

[[Pandas make new column from string slice of another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25789445/pandas-make-new-column-from-string-slice-of-another-column][1])

df['group'] = df.Name.str[3:5]