# Iterate through rows and populate them with range()

Tags: python, pandas

I have been trying to look for this specific question but I cannot seem to find it so apologies in advance if there has been a previous thread asking the same question.

I have a df with football seasons but the format is a bit awkward (see below). I want to create a new column that goes from year 1929 to 2020 (see 'season_new')

```
   Season   season_new
0  1929     1929
1  1929-30  1930
2  1930-31  1931
3  1931-32  1932
```

Anyone can help me?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
df['season_new'] = df['Season'].apply(lambda d: d[:2] + d[-2:])
```

Comment: Note using apply may be slower than just slicing the strings directly (i.e. the "vectorized" approach): https://stackoverflow.com/a/25789512/1011724

Comment: That's great. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

So you want to concatenate first 2 and last 2 characters of `Season`?

```
df['season_new'] = df['Season'].str[:2] + df['Season'].str[-2:]
```