# Slice string in multiple column with same condition

Tags: python, string, slice

I have multiple column that I need to slice with same condition I can see some solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25789445/pandas-make-new-column-from-string-slice-of-another-column) but they do not work with multiple column

```
df['x', 'y']=df['x', 'y'].str.slice(0,19)
```

Error

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `apply` function to a apply it on multiple columns:

```
df[['x','y']]=df[['x','y'].apply(lambda x:x.str.slice(0,19))
```

It should give the correct output.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [applymap()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) method

```py
import pandas as pd

df_exp = pd.DataFrame([('ABCDEF', 'GHIJKL')], columns=["x", "y"])

print(df_exp.head(10))
#         x       y
# 0  ABCDEF  GHIJKL

your_slice_func = lambda x: x[0:3]
df_result = df_exp.applymap(your_slice_func)

print(df_result.head(10))
#      x    y
# 0  ABC  GHI
```