# How to substring values from a pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df with much values like that BB1283980901 and i have to separate all the two first values witch will aways be two  letters. How do i can do it, pls?

Comment: Guys, i forgot. My df have much columns and one unique column with values like that from question. And i have to create a new column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`str.extract()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) is an option, where `(..)` captures the first two characters, and `(.*)` gets the rest:

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"X": ["BB1283980901", "AA1283980901"]})
>>> df
              X
0  BB1283980901
1  AA1283980901
>>> df[["prefix", "foobar"]] = df.X.str.extract("(..)(.+)")
>>> df
              X prefix      foobar
0  BB1283980901     BB  1283980901
1  AA1283980901     AA  1283980901
```

Comment: Thanks man. It worked. it was exactly what i needed

Comment: Man, what if i have to extract the number "398"? Or another number, can u help me?

Comment: It depends. Do you need *any* consecutive 3 digits? Or the slice `[5:7]` (in which case the answer by Dhiraj Eadara would be useful)?

Answer (score 1):

You can perform string slicing on columns as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"s":["BB1283980901"]})

df['s1'] = df['s'].str[:2]
df['s2'] = df['s'].str[2:]

print(df)
```

Please check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25789512/18511682) for more info

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).